# Looping through list of images and adding to zip download issue

Tags: php, wordpress, php-ziparchive

I have the following code that essentially grabs all Wordpress images added by the user "65'. I then try and zip all those images and download.

The issue I have is that it only zips the last image in the foreach.

I have no idea what's wrong and am looking for some expert guidance.

Many thanks.

```
# get all attachments (images) for user ID 65
$pictures = new WP_Query( array( 'author' => '65', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_status' => 'inheret', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

if ( $pictures->posts ) :
    foreach ( $pictures->posts as $picture ) :
         if (wp_get_attachment_image_url($picture->ID, 'full')) :
         
            $files = array(wp_get_attachment_image_url( $picture->ID, 'full' ));
            if ($files) :
                //echo $files;
                
                # create new zip opbject
                $zip = new ZipArchive();
                
                # create a temp file & open it
                $tmp_file = tempnam('.','');
                $zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);
                
                # loop through each file
                foreach($files as $file){
                
                    # download file
                    $download_file = file_get_contents($file);
                
                    #add it to the zip
                    $zip->addFromString(basename($file),$download_file);
                
                }
                
                $zip->close();
                ob_clean();
                # send the file to the browser as a download
                $datestamp = date("d-M-Y", time());
                header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=Backup-65-'.$datestamp.'.zip');
                header('Content-type: application/zip');
                readfile($tmp_file);


            endif;
        endif;
    endforeach;
endif;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a new `ZipArchive` instance on every iteration. Move all operations except adding of the file outside the loop.

```
# get all attachments (images) for user ID 65
$pictures = new WP_Query( array( 'author' => '65', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_status' => 'inheret', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

if ( $pictures->posts ) :

    # create new zip opbject
    $zip = new ZipArchive();
                
    # create a temp file & open it
    $tmp_file = tempnam('.','');
    $zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

    foreach ( $pictures->posts as $picture ) :
    
            $file = wp_get_attachment_image_url($picture->ID, 'full');
            
            # download file
            $download_file = file_get_contents($file);
                
            #add it to the zip
            $zip->addFromString(basename($file),$download_file);
    endforeach;
    
    $zip->close();
    ob_clean();
    # send the file to the browser as a download
    $datestamp = date("d-M-Y", time());
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=Backup-65-'.$datestamp.'.zip');
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    readfile($tmp_file);

endif;
```

Comment: I think that inner foreach loop is completely superfluous to begin with. `wp_get_attachment_image_url` will only ever return _one_ image URL.

Comment: @CBroe You're right, the array is created on the spot.

Comment: OMG! How on earth did I miss that. Thank you so much for your time and input, it's very much appreciated.

Comment: I have fully tested this and it works as expected. Thanks!